# Installing e-sim on the device using the operator's application

Tags: javascript, android, capacitor, e-sim

Please help. I am developing applications for a mobile operator and we want to install e-sim from our application, I use a capacitor, I did not find a ready-made solution, so I wrote my own plugin, used the Android documentation.
Now I'm stuck at the moment of activation, we made the carrier's [privileges](https://source.android.com/docs/core/connect/esim-overview#carrier-privileges), loaded the key and id into the profile.
During the installation of the LPA link, I see the following in logcat:

```
**Permission Denial: broadcasting Intent { act=download_subscription flg=0x10 (has extras)**
```

The AndroidManifest file has the following permissions:

```
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EMBEDDED_SUBSCRIPTIONS" 
uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_PHONE_STATE"
```

For me, working with this for the first time, you can say I'm a beginner, I will be glad and grateful for any help.

Tried to change permissions, do debugging, maybe I missed something in the specification? How can I check if I have e-sim privileges? How to do it with capacitor ?

UPDATE:
**I was able to overcome this problem, so please contact :)**

The solution was to add an intet-filter pair:

```
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.DOWNLOAD_SUBSCRIPTION" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /></intent-filter> 
<intent-filter><action android:name="android.intent.action.SWITCH_TO_SUBSCRIPTION" /><category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" /></intent-filter>
```

Comment: I am also stuck in this but i am using flutter and writing code for esim. installation in android kotlin. Could you please share the glimpse of code so i can get the idea the official docs are not helping?